# How to embed mp3 flash player within site which plays from a URL instead of XML

Tags: php, mp3, flash

I would like to include a mp3 file preview feature which should enable a person, once he/she has uploaded an mp3 file.

He should be able to listen/preview it within the site.

How can this be accomplished and are there any flash mp3 player which do this. All  have seen are all XML based.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be: http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone

Answer (score 0):

You may try: http://www.macloo.com/examples/audio_player/